# Is there a maximum number of groups?

Tags: ssh, user-management

We started an Ubuntuserver for versioncontrol and would like to access our repositories via ssh.
As we need to give access to several external developers I thought it would be the best way to create a group per project and add the users to it which should use the repository. I cannot say how many projects will be created in the future, so I wonder if we could run into problems later.

Is there a maximum number of existing groups or groups of which a user can be member of in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are limits. Linux now supports 65536 groups but you will need to use ACLs and [RPCSEC_GSS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/gssd.8.html) and NFS version 4.0 or higher if you need more than 16 since AUTH_SYS historically has a [limit](http://www.insectnation.org/articles/2007/05/08/linux-nfs-16-group-limit) of [16 groups](http://nfsworld.blogspot.nl/2005/03/whats-deal-on-16-group-id-limitation.html).

Besides the NFS<4.0 limit of 16:

- Linux Kernel >= 2.6.3: 65536
- Linux Kernel < 2.6.3: 32

Comment: Narf. I guess we need to reconsider that...many thanks, especially for the helful links!

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of groups [is up to 2<sup>32</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Feature_history) starting with version 2.6.0 of the Linux kernel, like the maximum number of users. Still, one user can be a member of at [maximum 32 groups on a modern linux](https://superuser.com/questions/26599/how-many-unix-groups-can-a-user-be-a-member-of).

Comment: quoting another answer that has no documentation on the 32 groups? 32 is kernel 2.6 and lower. Plus there is a link in the answer pointing to a max of 65536 groups.